# View model id property same name as parameter in url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

In my mvc 4 and EF5 project I've a class that serves as database model as well as view model.
In that class the PK is a property called Id. In the view I load this Id in HiddenField using @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id). To load view first time typing the url I call an Action named Index(int? Id). 
The code for Action is below:

```
entry = context.Entries.Where(e => e.Id > Id.Value && e.Revised == false).First();
```

As you can see the Id I looking for is greater than passed in Url, that's ok, is what I want.

Now figure this out: I type an url like localhost/Index/Index/1609 e the next one will be 1610, but hidden field keeps the 1609. I figured out myself that it's related to property name 'Id' as I change the name and it work out as I expected.

Why this happens? What if I want use that way expecting behavior described before?

Comment: Seems like a good case study for not using Model objects as ViewModel objects. Subtle differences like this will kill you in the long run.

Comment: Sure did. The best approach, so, is to have both models? One for View and Another one for data?

Comment: A model and view model are concerned about totally different things, but they use a lot of the same "words" to describe what they are doing. You end up confusing yourself and breaking your separation of concerns when you try to merge them like this. A view model could be aware of the URL and extract the data correctly, then query the model to get the appropriate data.

Comment: If I've the two models, supposing, Class and ClassModel, the last one will be the View model, how persist that data coming from that ClassModel? Do I've to instance a Class and fill property by property, pass this freshy object to context and after call context.SaveChanges()?

Comment: That is often how it is done. Without seeing your project, though, it's difficult to recommend a particular approach. Even though it sounds like a lot of work, a textbox and a database column are separate things with different roles and rules. Trying to mash them together is going to lead to more and more headaches - it is best to separate them.